# Retrieving Specific MySQL Field Data in PHP Based on Primary Key Value Instead of Row Number

Tags: php, mysql, database, reference, get

I'm trying to find the correct way of pulling specific field data from a MySQL database and referencing it on a web page, using the primary key (an INT) in the row of data instead of the row number. we tried:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM ourTable";
$result = mysql_result($sql, $con);
echo mysql_results($sql,$con);
echo mysql_result($result, 2, "pageTitle");
echo "<br />";
echo mysql_result($result, 2, "pageDate");`
```

But this returns values based on row number. Instead we would like to make reference to the pageID in our database to populate the pageTitle and pageDate information.

(The $con variable is referenced before this block)

so say in my database I have:

pageID    pageTitle    pageDate
 
001            Page1       1885

002            Page2       1976

003            Page3        1776

As an example, on the web page, the data will be printed like:

Title: Page1

Date: 1885

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Do you only want a single row? If this is the case, you should change your query to `SELECT * FROM ourTable WHERE pageID=1885` (of course substituting whatever value you need).

Answer (score 0):

Your query is selecting all rows from the table. You later extract a row by its position in the results array. However, you should **never** make any assumptions about the order that your rows are stored or returned, **unless** you're using the `ORDER BY` keyword. Otherwise, you're not guaranteed that your rows will be returned in the order that you inserted them.

Like MichaelMior said, you can use the WHERE keyword to select a row based on the value of a column.

```
$id = "001";
$sql = "SELECT * FROM ourTable WHERE pageID='$id'";
$result = mysql_result($sql, $con);

// Since you're selecting based on a unique key, you'll get only 0 or 1 rows
if( mysql_num_rows($result) == 1)
{
  // Parse the result
  echo mysql_result($result, 0, "pageTitle");
  echo "<br />";
  echo mysql_result($result, 0, "pageDate");
}
```

Edit, clarification: A **[primary key](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primary_key)** is by definition unique.

Comment: This is basically what I'm looking for, but It's not quite working. No errors are being returned but where the pageTitle and pageDate information should be printed, it is just blank.

Comment: Are you getting into the `if` block in my code? That is, are you getting one row in the result set? Also, if pageID is stored as a string, then you need to quote the search string in your query. I forgot to do that but I just edited my answer and fixed that.